# Why is clang not computing fibonacci(500) with a constexpr version of fibonacci?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I was trying things with `constexpr`:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr long long fibonacci(const int x)
{
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2);
}

int main()
{
    const long long lol = fibonacci(500);
    std::cout << lol << std::endl;
}
```

So I want `lol` to be computed at compile time:

```
toogy@stewie
» g++ -std=c++14 -g src/test.cc -o test.out
toogy@stewie
» ./test.out 
4859788740867454402
```

It's working really well with `g++`. At compilation it's even doing some memoization, optimizing this crappy fibonnaci function and then computing `fibonacci(500)` instantly.

Then I try with `clang++`:

```
toogy@stewie
» clang++ -std=c++1y -g src/test.cc -o test.out 
toogy@stewie
» ./test.out
... very long
```

`lol` is not computed at compile time by `clang++` (proved by `gdb`). **Why?**

Comment: Also, g++ is calculating something, but not the 500th Fibonacci number. It's overflowing very quickly. Not even the 30th would fit in a long long.

Comment: According to [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cmdoption-fconstexpr-depth), the default depth of a constexpr recursion invocation is 512. So I guess there is no problem related to it. I think the chances are of an integer overflow, as mentioned by @Cornstalks

Comment: Also, clang/gcc might be detecting some overflow, and since signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, they might produce different results. (given that the 500th fibonacci number is [139423224561697880139724382870407283950070256587697307264108962948325571622863290691557658876222521294125](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci+number+500))

Comment: @Cornstalks lol, yea... Overflow chances are strong with this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It hits clang's maximum recursion depth. You can force `lol` to be evaluated at compile time by making it `constexpr`, i.e.:

```
constexpr long long lol = fibonacci(500);
```

Doing that and compiling with `clang++ -std=c++11 t.cpp` gives the errors:

```
t.cpp:10:25: error: constexpr variable 'lol' must be initialized by a constant
      expression
    constexpr long long lol = fib(500);
                        ^     ~~~~~~~~
t.cpp:4:1: note: constexpr evaluation hit maximum step limit; possible infinite
      loop?
{
^
t.cpp:5:38: note: in call to 'fib(4)'
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
                                     ^
t.cpp:5:25: note: in call to 'fib(6)'
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
                        ^
t.cpp:5:38: note: in call to 'fib(7)'
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
                                     ^
t.cpp:5:25: note: in call to 'fib(9)'
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
                        ^
t.cpp:5:25: note: in call to 'fib(10)'
t.cpp:5:25: note: (skipping 480 calls in backtrace; use
      -fconstexpr-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
t.cpp:5:25: note: in call to 'fib(496)'
t.cpp:5:25: note: in call to 'fib(497)'
t.cpp:5:25: note: in call to 'fib(498)'
t.cpp:5:25: note: in call to 'fib(499)'
t.cpp:10:31: note: in call to 'fib(500)'
    constexpr long long lol = fib(500);
                              ^
1 error generated.
```

Clang can't (with default compiler flags; though I still couldn't get it to compile with `-fconstexpr-depth=1000000000` (that's 1 billion)) evaluate `fibonacci(500)` at compile time, so it instead does it at runtime with the code you've posted. As @Streppel links to, you can increase the maximum recursion depth for constant expressions using the `-fconstexpr-depth=N` compiler flag.

However, the 500th fibonacci number is huge*, so this will certainly overflow, which is undefined behavior for signed integers (so all bets are off, really). ([But you can do it if you use template metaprogramming](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/637130-hows-your-template-metaprogramming-ninja-skills/))

<sup>*[as in 105 digits huge](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci+number+500): 139423224561697880139724382870407283950070256587697307264108962948325571622863290691557658876222521294125</sup>